# extension stopped after max setTimeout calls reached

Tags: google-chrome-extension

hello every ome I am developping a new chrome extension that notify users about last news in their favourite sites.

so I use this:

```
function getNews() {
    setTimeout(getNews,300000);
    // some code
 }
```

and in my manifest file I checked that all permissions are granted

additionally my extension has background permission and it works well but my problem that it stops because of max calls reached

are there any APIs that I can use and how?

Comment: chrome.alarms API.

Comment: does it has max calls limit and how I can use it. thanks

Comment: I have no idea, but if you hit that limit, your code is incorrect.

Comment: do you mean that chrome.alarms didn't have limit.

Comment: I have no idea what limit you are talking about, but if you hit it, your code is incorrect.